# Is DBContext persist data through deployments?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am looking at implementing token cache for ADAL using DbContext as shown in the below example:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect/tree/master/TodoListWebApp/DAL

I believe the data is stored in the ldf and mdf files under App_data folder.

A couple of questions:

1. Does the data persists when the app is redeployed?
2. Our site is hosted on multiple servers under VIP. How can we synchronize the user data across all the servers if we implement DbContext?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> I believe the data is stored in the ldf and mdf files under App_data folder.

Yes, by default it is. But the location is specified in the ConnectionString. You can use a dedicated database server.

> 1. Does the data persists when the app is redeployed?

Depends on how you treat the database. It should be preserved, and maybe have its schema updated through scripts.

> 2. Our site is hosted on multiple servers under VIP. How can we synchronize the user data across all the servers if we implement DbContext?

Just point all ConnectionStrings to the same SQL Db.

Answer (score 0):

DbContext is an abstraction. Where it persists its data is specified by the connection string.

You can let multiple apps on multiple servers talk to one database in order to let them share data.